# python self is not defined

Tags: python

**Context**

I'm using vscode. And just running script with all the project files in same folder worked fine. It is as below

```
MainModule
    -aFile.py
    -bFile.py
    -cFile.py
    -dFile.py
```

While working on my project, I decided that it should be better to separate project into two modules.

```
MainModule
    /subModule00
        -aFile.py
        -bFile.py
    /subModule01
        -cFile.py
        -dFile.py
```

After that, I needed to test cFile which imports class from aFile. Running it as script caused an error. So I ran cFile as module and it fixed the import error. But a new error rose.

**Question**

```
class ExampleClass(ClassFromAfile):
    EXAMPLE_CONSTANT = 1000
    def __init__(self, someArg0, someArg1):
        self.someVar = someArg0

    def exmapleMethod(self, someArg2, someArg3=1000, someArg=self.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT):
        # ... so on
```

While debugging below error occurred while defining exampleMehod

> name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You cannot refer to instance attributes as default values. The instance and class do not exist by the time the method is defined.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If you are referring to self.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT, it is a static variable. And I have tried to delete parameter, and the error still occurred.

Comment: If both of those don’t work, `self` may appear in more places within `exampleMethod`.

Comment: @Axium Thank you. I just found out that there were more parameters using self.

Comment: It does not matter that EXAMPLE_CONSTANT is static. You are accessing it through self, which is not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is not a reserved keyword in Python.
The first argument of a function in a class is the class instance, thus making it a *method* of the class. [Unless it is a static method (@staticmethod) or class method, in which case the first argument is the class itself (@classmethod) ]

In your example, you want to initialize `someArg` as a constant `EXAMPLE_CONSTANT`.
Then you can simply use as below:

```
class ExampleClass(ClassFromAfile):
    EXAMPLE_CONSTANT = 1000
    def __init__(self, someArg0, someArg1):
        self.someVar = someArg0

    def exmapleMethod(self, someArg2, someArg3=1000, someArg=EXAMPLE_CONSTANT):
        # ... so on
```

To make it clear you can do the following:

```
In [1]: class Test:
    ...:     def test(t_self, a):  # not using self and its good still
    ...:         print(a)
    ...:     def best(b):
    ...:         print(b)  # This will print out the class instance itself.
    ...:         

In [2]: te = Test()

In [3]: te.best()
<__main__.Test object at 0x7efc1294b278>

In [24]: te.test(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `exampleMethod`, `self` is used in `someArg = self.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT`. You should add `self` back to `EXAMPLE_CONSTANT` for it to work properly or remove `self.` from your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Both `def` and `class` are executable statements in Python, with the usual scoping and execution time rules. In this case, that means the `self` in the argument list doesn't exist when the `def` for the method is run. The default argument value expression `self.EXAMPLE_CONSTANT` gets evaluated when the `def` statement runs, and at that time `self` doesn't exist because the method hasn't been called, and `ExampleClass` doesn't exist because the `class` block has not finished (both `def` and `class` build an object, callable or class respectively, and assign it to a name). Note that this implies that while `def` defines a callable that is deferred until it is called, `class` actually executes everything inside; there are no variable or type declarations like in e.g. C++.

The `def` for the method runs with its local scope within the `class` block, so you could use a local reference to values that will be class members:

```
class Foo:
    bar=123
    def hmm(self, arg=bar):
        return arg
```

There's also a common workaround for when you need a default argument to be evaluated during a call, rather than at `def` time:

```
def append(someitem, somelist=None):
    if somelist is None:
        somelist = list()
    somelist.append(someitem)
    return somelist   # Caller needs this if we made a new list
```